# How can I display to in the dynamically created divs?

Tags: javascript, html

Html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="forWordsGame.js"></script>
    <style>
    div#board{
        background:#CCC;
        border:#999 1px solid;
        position:absolute;
        width:90%;
        height:540px;
        padding:20px;
        margin:20px, auto;
        position:relative;
    }


    div#guessing{
        background: red;
        border:#000 1px solid;

        width:121px;
        height:51px;
        float:center;

        margin: 30px;
    }
    div#wordsToGuessWrapper{
        background: green;
        border:#000 1px solid;
        position:relative;
        width:80%;
        height:200px;
        float:center;
        margin: 30px;
    }
    div#wordsToGuessWrapper > div{
        background: red;
        border:#000 1px solid;
        width:71px;
        height:71px;
        float:left;
        margin:50px;
        padding:20px;
        font-size:20px;
        cursor:pointer;
        text-align:center;
    }

    </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="myButton" type="button" value="Start game" />
        <div id="board">
            <div id="guessing">Guessing</div>
                <div id="wordsToGuessWrapper">

                </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Javascript

```
for (var i = 0; i < myFourWordsArray.length; i++) {
  // output += '<div id="tile_'+i+'" onclick="memoryFlipTile(this,\''+myFourWordsArray[i]+'\')"></div>';
  output += '<div id="tile_' + i + '"  " value="' + myFourWordsArray[i] + ' "   onclick="init1()"></div>';
}
document.getElementById('wordsToGuessWrapper').innerHTML = output;


[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('div.wordsToGuessWrapper'), function(div, i) {
  div.textContent = myFourWordsArray[i];
});
```

Please tell me how can I put values from my array myFourWordsArray into dynamically created divs. The values from array myFourWordsArray appear when I look the site code but not inside each of the divs. I need one value per each of four dynamically created divs.

Comment: `'div.wordsToGuessWrapper'` isn't a tag name, is it. Use `document.querySelectorAll` to use a selector to fetch elements, or just concatenate them in the `for` loop like you're already doing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to iterate through an array and add it to an HTML element. You can see a live example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ptsqtnfx/):

```
var arr = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'durian']
var section = document.querySelector('section')
arr.forEach(function (fruit) {
  var div = document.createElement('div')
  div.classList.add('my-class')
  div.textContent = fruit
  section.appendChild(div)
})
```

In your case you would use something like `document.querySelector('div#wordsToGuessWrapper')`